# ChromeDrive - unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Here is my problem: run a selenium test with chrome.

I do this:

```
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.setBinary("/Applications/Google/Google Chrome.app");
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/Users/Blabla/Documents/lib/chrome/chromedriver");
```

And when I do `mvn test`, I get this error:

```
    unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary
```

Comment: is there a specific reason you are explicitely trying to set your google chrome executable?  Selenium will automatically find that installation.

Comment: That's what i'm trying to do. Do a test on various navigator. I can make the test with Firefox, but not with Chrome

Comment: @Mxfrd : Did you install google chrome in your machine?

Comment: did you find any answer ? @Mxfrd

Answer (score 2):

According to the [ChromeDriver Capabilities docs](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/capabilities):

> Path to the Chrome executable to use (on Mac OS X, this should be the
>   actual binary, not just the app. e.g., '/Applications/Google
>   Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome')

So you need to locate your application in the Finder and do 'Show Package Contents'

Comment: Test this and same error again... My path is : /Applications/Google/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS

Comment: My bad ! But i correctly write it in my code and that's the same.. Not working :/

Comment: Hmm, you could try wrapping it in a new File("<path>") to validate that path is OK. I'm thinking about the space in there. Maybe backslash the spaces?

Comment: I have changed the path removing the spaces, not working too ...  Started ChromeDriver (v2.1) on port 28164
2016-02-04 09:23:14.542 chromedriver3[450:2607] *** __NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x10e9c0 of class NSCFArray autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
Msg error and the " cannot find Chrome binary " msg ..

Comment: Strange - but 2.1 is pretty old (http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.21/notes.txt). I wouldn't normally demand people upgrade, but try 2.21 in case it is a bug. If still no, would really have to see more of your code just in case we missed something.